# html5 audio + javascript + ajax

Tags: ajax, html, audio

I have a problem to keep working the controls of a player in html5 "" via javascript on the page after an ajax request occurs.

When the page is loaded, the player starts playing and "Play, Pause, Next, Prev" controls work, but after I access any other page with ajax request, the controls no longer work.

The controls are within div.content which has its recharged every ajax request content.

If they want to see in practice http://devintec.com/dev/jjsv

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're attaching your event handler after page load, so whenever the controls div is updated, the event handlers disappear (because the DOM elements that had them attached are removed). You'll have to attach the event handlers again after your AJAX call completes, or use event delegation.

Comment: I solved the problem by placing the player on top of page, where the elements were not reloaded with ajax.

Comment: @Oscar, can you please explain this a bit more for me? I have a very similar problem, but I have no idea how to attach the event handlers again after the AJAX call completes or use event delegation. Here is my query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26123839/moving-html5-players-through-the-dom-with-setinterval-players-stop-working